# Coverity Eclipse Plugin fails during test connection

Tags: eclipse-plugin, client-certificates, coverity

I have the Eclipse Coverity desktop plugin installed and have set up my coverity connect URL. I do not have the "Use extra CA certificates" enabled

When I click on Test Connection, I get the following:

```
Cannot establish connection to the server.
IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for
URL: https://coverity...com/ws/v9/configurationservice?wsdl
```

Also, in the "Authentication Key" part of the dialog box it says:

> Key for username 'myUserName' is not available. Please import or generate a new key.

I have imported the key that I generated when I logged into the address above (our coverity connect server).

I am connected via a VPN and the same https:// address loads fine in a browser window.

Do I need to do anything extra for certificates? I started off by splitting my original .pfx certificate, but for coverity, I'm not sure if I need additional steps for my certificate.

I tried copying three certificates to the directory:

```
C:\coverity\cov-analysis-win64-2021.06\certs

ca.crt
client.cert
client.key
```

I also tried some "keytool" in the jre\lib to see if I can somehow get the jre to read my certificates.

Coverity version: cov-analysis-win64-2021.06
Eclipse version: 2021-12 (4.22.0)